# Keep nested route active

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have these routes :

```
{
  path: '/projects',
  name: 'projects',
  meta: {
    title: 'Projects',
    documentTitle: '*pages.projects.title',
    empty: true,
  },
  component: () => import('@/views/Projects.vue'),
},
{
  path: '/projects/:id',
  name: 'projects-keys',
  meta: {
    title: 'Projects Keys',
    empty: true,
  },
  component: () => import('@/views/ProjectsKeys.vue'),
},
```

Now in my sidenav file : `Sidenav.vue` :

```
<router-link
    :to="{ name: 'projects' }"
    exact
    class="sidenav-menu-item"
    tag="li"
  >
    <a :style="currentBackground">
      <icon class="icon" width="19" height="19" type="properties"/>
      <span>{{ $t('pages.projects.title') }}</span>
    </a>
</router-link>
```

When I click on `Projects` from sidenav, all good, I have this options active.

Now I want to keep option `Projects` active when I access route : `/projects/10`. When I access this route, my `Projects` option is inactive. How can I resolve this?

Comment: I think you could wrap your Projects.vue in a `<keep-alive> ... </keep-alive>` or?

Comment: I tried, but not working